# Проблема в методе Move TextField, при появлении клавиатуры все что на Вью двигается?

Tags: ios, swift, клавиатура, uitextfield

у меня экран регистрации, когда вводишь текст не видно поля textfielda что вводишь.Нашел уроки изучил и сделал метод.Textfield поднимается и почему то двигается весь Экран вью что расположено на ней и показывается под этой вью еще черный экран.Это так должно быть? И как то смотрится убого. Прикрепляю скриншот и код.Буду благодарен за помощь.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapView))
        tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }


    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        moveTextField(textField, moveDistance: -250, up: true)
    }

    // Finish Editing The Text Field
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        moveTextField(textField, moveDistance: -250, up: false)
    }
    func moveTextField(_ textField: UITextField, moveDistance: Int, up: Bool) {
        let moveDuration = 0.3
        let movement: CGFloat = CGFloat(up ? moveDistance : -moveDistance)

        UIView.beginAnimations("animateTextField", context: nil)
        UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
        UIView.setAnimationDuration(moveDuration)
        self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement)
        UIView.commitAnimations()
    }


    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == usernameTF {
            usernameTF.resignFirstResponder()
        }

        if textField == countryTF {
            countryTF.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        if textField == emailTF {
            emailTF.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        if textField == passwordTF {
           passwordTF.becomeFirstResponder()
        }

        return true
    }

    @objc func didTapView() {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не вижу ошибок в коде. Скорее всего это глюк Симулятора, если вы убиралии добавляли клавиатуру с помощью Cmnd+K . На устройстве такого поведения я не получал. А вот на симуляторе обычное дело.

Comment: Вы не поняли, видите все view серое на котором расположены  texfield так когда нажимаешь оно двигается, это нормально? я понял только textfield-ы должны подниматься.Я вот думаю может создать еще одну view прозрачную .А то как то стремно получается.

Comment: Так вы же приказали всей вьюхе двигаться.                                                              self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: movement) Потому она вся и поехала вверх.